# Apply targetSdk in Android Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am working on a multi module Android Project.

In Android Gradle Plugin, 7.4.0 they have deprecated the `targetSdk` property for library module. [Root Isssue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230625468) . It might be removed in AGP 9.0. Deprecated Property [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/LibraryBaseFlavor#targetSdk()).

If I remove the property , the Android Instrumentation Tests are breaking.

Its throwing the below error

> " Exception thrown during onBeforeAll invocation of plugin
> com.google.testing.platform.plugin.android.AndroidDevicePlugin. Failed
> to install APK(s):
> -26: Package com.test   new target SDK 21 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 33 does."

My **build.gradle** in library module:

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33 // Deprecated Property
    }
}
```

It is taking given minSdk as default targetSdk Version if not provided

I see there is a separate flavour for applying test configuration. Link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/TestBaseFlavor). For this `targetSdk` property is not deprecated yet.
I couldn't able to apply this test flavour settings in my **build.gradle** file.

Answer (score 0):

As of AGP 8.2.2 (maybe before), there is `testOptions.targetSdk`